# Create report of images with desrcriptions

Tags: python, image, report, dashboard

What is the most convenient way in Python ecosystem,
to create a kind of **report** of a few hundred small images.

Where each image has a description (metadata).

Comment: do you mean like libraries or packages that can be used to perform the task ?

Comment: Exactly. Meanwhile, I found only `reportlab` and `fpfdf`.

Comment: Have you found the libraries for reading the images ?

Comment: There is a lot of libraries, to read images, like matplotlib and others. I'm interesting, to create a light "final report" in html, pdf or any other way with small image and some description.